# Button does not work when I create it through .aspx.cs

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

When I do that in the home.aspx file everything works great

```
<form>
    <button type="button" id="aaa" value="0" onclick="showQuestionJS(this.id)">[time1]: titel1</button>
    <button type="button" id="nnn" value="1" onclick="showQuestionJS(this.id)">[time2]: titel2</button>
    <button type="button" id="rrr" value="2" onclick="showQuestionJS(this.id)">[time3]: titel3</button>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showQuestionJS(id_of_the_button)
    {
        alert(document.getElementById(id_of_the_button).value)
    }
</script>
```

But when I try to create the button through the home.aspx.cs, the button created but when I click it does not show id in the alert:

home.aspx:

```
<% tempFucntion(); %>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function showQuestionJS(id_of_the_button)
    {
        alert(document.getElementById(id_of_the_button).value)
    }
</script>
```

home.aspx.cs:

```
protected void tempFucntion()
    {
        Response.Write("<button type=\"button\" id=\"fff\" \value=\"3\" onclick=\"showQuestionJS(this.id)\">[time4]: titel4</button>");
    }
```

I do not know why this happens or how it can be fixed

I'd like to get some help

Comment: You should not add anything to your webpage via `Response.Write`. You should add controls as children of other controls on the page. With `Response.Write`, you have no control over where the markup ends up in your page.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra backslash at

```
id=\"fff\" \value=\"3\"
-----------^
```